# Regular Expression to find multiple instances of same word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will only find the word "icmp" when repeated more than 5 times.  I'm trying "permit icmp{6,20} but I guess that only works when there isn't any line breaks between them.  Is there a regex that'll trigger only when finding more than 5 instances of a word?  Below is an example of some text that I would like for this regex to find.  Notice there are 6 lines that have the word "icmp" in it.  Is it possible for regex to find this?

130 permit gre object-group RemoteTunnel object-group LocalTunnel
140 permit esp object-group RemoteTunnel object-group LocalTunnel (63043121 matches)
150 permit icmp object-group bcbsscnets object-group augustanets echo-reply (35251 matches)
160 permit icmp object-group bcbsscnets object-group augustanets packet-too-big
170 permit icmp object-group bcbsscnets object-group augustanets source-quench
180 permit icmp object-group bcbsscnets object-group augustanets time-exceeded (17 matches)
190 permit icmp object-group bcbsscnets object-group augustanets parameter-problem
200 permit icmp object-group snmpmgr object-group augustanets echo (207603 matches)
210 permit udp 1.1.1.1 eq ntp 1.1.1.1 eq ntp
220 permit udp 1.1.1.1 eq ntp 1.1.1.1 eq ntp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex :

```
(.?icmp.?){6,20}
```

If you want "icmp" to be a word, use this one :

```
(.?\bicmp\b.?){6,20}
```

Comment: That seems to work very well when searching a single line for "icmp icmp icmp icmp icmp icmp..." I need a regex to hit on the word "icmp" appearing more than five times randomly throught multiple lines.  Is this possible with regex?